# Installing Adobe ColdFusion Splendor on Ubuntu 14, Apache 2

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm installing the Adobe ColdFusion Splendor Beta on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 and Apache 2 set up on a Parallels VM.

When I set up the Apache connector configuration, I used the following settings:

**Apache Configuration Files:**  `/etc/apache2`

**Apache Binary file:**  `/usr/sbin/apache2`

**Apache control file:**  `/etc/init.d/apache2`

All of this has been successful for me in the past when I installed CF10 on a Ubuntu 12.04 server.

However... when I try to do this under the configuration I listed above, I get the following error:

> There was an error while running the connector wizard.
>       Connector installation was not successful.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Doing some Google searches, I saw a couple of entries that suggested that the Apache information I entered above was incorrect, but I'm confident these are the correct files/paths.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: did the install procedure create a log file?

Comment: What does the wsconfig.log output?

Comment: What is the exact Apache version?

Comment: My apologies for the delay.  Ask a question, pass out is a bad idea.  :)

Comment: The important parts of the WSconfig.log is:  04/28 08:34:37 debug command line: -ws Apache -dir /etc/apache2 -bin /usr/sbin/apache2 -script /etc/init.d/apache2 -cfide /opt/coldfusionsplendor/cfusion/wwwroot/CFIDE -v 
04/28 08:34:37 debug Using Apache binary /usr/sbin/apache2
04/28 08:34:37 error Could not determine Apache connector version.
Check that the Apache binary path /usr/sbin/apache2 is correct.

Comment: The Apache version is 2.4.7.  There is a log file for installation, but it wasn't the installation that failed, it's the connector to the web server that's causing a problem.

Comment: ColdFusion 11 has been officially released today (no longer in beta). Perhaps you should try downloading the latest version and see if it plays nicer. [ColdFusion product page](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family.html)

Answer (score 0):

The final ColdFusion 11 installer has resolved this problem, using the following files:

Apache Configuration Files: /etc/apache2

Apache Binary file: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl

Apache control file: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl